# Hanging a large ceramic plate

Tags: hanging

I have a large ceramic plate that I wanted to hang in my kitchen.  It is 22" in diameter and it's circular.  It weighs almost 15 lbs.  Is this a possibility?  I don't see any plate hangers out on the internet that can accommodate the circumference and handle the weight.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Get drywall anchors that are the plastic kind that screw into the drywall.  Home Depot sells these.  Then when the anchor is in thread in a wood screw and hang the plate off that.  Twist-n-lock for example is one of that style.  Google "Brass Plate Hanger Displays Plates on Wall Size 5 to image" off etsy for what you need for the plate itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could put it on a plate shelf - a shelf that has a groove in it that the edge of the plate sits in to prevent it from sliding off.